# Using a dash in Struts 2 action name

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2

I have the following action:

```xml
<action name="#dash_creds" class="AccountDashboardActionBean">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        <param name="inputName">jsonInputStream</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

I want Struts to accept the `#` symbol in my URL or to ignore it, for now it does not call my action.

Comment: How about `namespace` anyway I think when you want to use suchkind of special characters you need to think of their encoding into url.. can you post your `jsp` or action caller process here ..

Comment: Why do you want to use special characters in the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

The hash symbol is used to identify the "fragment" part of the URL; everything after the first `#` in a url is treated as part of the fragment and it is not sent to the server.

This means that an action name with a # in it will never be reached; if you call this from the browser:

`http://domain.name/namespace/#dash_creds`

your Struts application will see:

`http://domain.name/namespace/`

For the same reason, I don't think there's a way to make Struts "ignore it". Your action name should not include an hash.

See also these links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier
- https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

Answer (score 0):

The special character `#` is not allowed as a part of the action name. If you want to build url using the action name, you can use url tag.

```
<s:url var="url" action="" anchor="dash_creds"/>
```